# Deploying sample GWT app to Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, gwt, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a very basic GWT app to tomcat and running into problems. I took the sample GWT project in eclipse, tested it to make sure it ran, then right clicked and selected google > gwt compile. I then took the war file, zipped it up and renamed it gwtproject.war. I then went into tomcat and slected deploy from the menu, and deployed the project. Yet every time I navigate to localhost:808/GwtProject I get a 404 error.

From what I've gathered reading several posts this looks like its an .xml configuration issue. I have not changed the default xml file nor its location, but do I have to modify it and move it up to the root folder? If so, what exactly do I have to modify in it? This is my first time working with tomcat, and while I read the documentation I'm still at a loss, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this step:

> I then took the war file, zipped it up and renamed it gwtproject.war

Do not make the war file zip and rename to war, because that is a war file in a non war file :) 
war file has manifest, zip not.

Just take the original war file ( without zipping) and deploy that one.